# How can I enable wake-on-lan permanently?

Tags: networking, wakeonlan

I want to enable wake-on-lan for my network cards, for always. The [community guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan) recommends adding the relevant command to `/etc/network/interfaces`. In past experiences editing Ubuntu conf files, it's extremely likely that the network interface file is written anew every boot, if not every apt upgrade. What's the best way to ensure that wake-on-lan is enabled every boot?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A boot script run after the network cards are configured should do the trick. Ubuntu uses upstart. After reading about upstart jobs, ethtool, writing an upstart script, and searching the interwebs for a better solution, I came up with [this](https://gist.github.com/721245) from [jevinskie](https://github.com/jevinskie) (you'll want to put this in a file in `/etc/init`):

```
start on started network

script
    for interface in $(cut -d: -f1 /proc/net/dev | tail -n +3); do
        logger -t 'wakeonlan init script' enabling wake on lan for $interface
        ethtool -s $interface wol g
    done
end script
```

- Starts when the nics are initialised
- Grabs the nic names from /proc/net/dev
- Logs actions to syslog
- Acts on all nics found
- Requires ethtool, so make sure it's installed first:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ethtool
  ```

If you want to imbue just one nic with the power of awakening, something like this is more appropriate:

```
start on started network

script
    interface=eth0
    logger -t 'wakeonlan init script' enabling wake on lan for $interface
    ethtool -s $interface wol g
end script
```

Comment: I always thought wake on lan was a BIOS feature.

Comment: @con-f-use It requires cooperation between BIOS and NIC. Both must support WOL. Furthermore, at least *my* nic has a bad habit of disabling wol after boot. The Ubuntu community wiki implies this is the case for many a computer.

Comment: @con-f-use This superuser.sx thread on [how power and rebooting works](http://superuser.com/questions/294681/how-does-a-computer-restart-itself) is also interesting as it relates to WOL.

Comment: Does this need to be changed for systemd?

Comment: @NathanOsman please add a systemd answer! this solution is still relevant to older but still supported LTS releases

Answer (score 3):

Create new file, let's say `wakeonlanconfig`, and put below lines to it:

```
#!/bin/bash
ethtool -s eth0 wol g
exit
```

Next set the permissions of the file, making it executable:

```
chmod a+x wakeonlanconfig
```

And finally make the script run on startup:

```
update-rc.d -f wakeonlanconfig defaults
```

For mor details please visit: http://lukasz-lademann.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-set-up-wol-wake-on-lan-on-thin.html

Answer (score 3):

For me, using [Netplan](https://netplan.io/) configurations worked (both for enabling and disabling WOL) since I am using Ubuntu.

Check [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1436788/818775) about how to enable it. Canonical also provided some nice documentation on how to use Netplan:

- [Netplan YAML configurations](https://netplan.io/reference#backend-specific-configuration-parameters)
- [Testing a Netplan YAML config](https://netplan.io/faq/#test-a-configuration)

### Steps I followed

For my specific case, I wanted to disable Wake on Lan, but this boils down to just setting a boolean to `true`/`false`.

1. I created this Netplan config YAML (you need sudo access to create a file in that dir):

```yaml
# /etc/netplan/02-disable-wol.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth-no-wakeonlan:
      match:
        macaddress: "11:22:33:44:55:66" # The eth interface's MAC address
      wakeonlan: false # To enable, set to true
      dhcp4: false # To enable, set to true
```

2. To test this configuration, I ran `sudo netplan try`, which applies the configurations for some minutes before reverting.
   NOTE: Apparently, it's a known bug that `netplan try` fails to revert the configs. [This tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/netplan-network-configuration-tutorial-for-beginners) says that a reboot should be enough (and deleting the yaml file, I assume)
3. Then, I had to open the Ubuntu Network Settings UI to switch to the newly created ethernet interface `netplan-eth-no-wakeonlan`.
4. Done!

On boot, Ubuntu should read all the files in `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` and apply their configs.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 additionally set `WOL_DISABLE=N` in `/etc/default/tlp` to avoid getting WOL disabled by TLP power management.

http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html

Add `NETDOWN=no` in `/etc/default/halt` to prevent powering off the network card during shutdown