# Access Ubuntu through windows

Tags: boot, command-line

I have a Ubuntu server that I normally control through Putty, but sometimes it dont want to boot up and then I cant use Putty and have to move my monitor and keyboard to where my server is at and boot it up (Which is troublesome) is there something I can use to access it through when it fails to boot up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on capabilities of your server's motherboard you may want to look for wake-on-lan. There is a solution here for 11.04 on how to make that permanent:

[How can I enable wake-on-lan permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47918/how-can-i-enable-wake-on-lan-permanently)

This however obviously will not work in case your server is unable to boot. A proper running OS is a prerequisite to access it remotely.

Comment: That wont help me then, will have to get a cheap wireless keyboard and a 10M vga cable to fix it when it gets stuck