# How to reboot ubuntu server machine from outside

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am at the office right now and my ubuntu server is at home. I was connected to my server few minutes ago when I got this message :

"ssh: connect to host port 22: No route to host"

Maybe this is a silly question but I was wondering if there is a way how to reboot that server while not beign phisically there? I am almost 100% sure that a reboot will fix the problem and will restore that machine.

I can ping my other laptop so the network at home is working fine.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at my [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/297198/remotely-turning-on-computer/297201#297201), see if it helps.

Comment: Very nice solution but unfortunately I dont know the MAC address of the server :( I tried to connect ssh to my other PC and ran the command "arp -a" and by the MAC address info it says "<incomplete>" The full line is: "? (192.168.1.11) at <incomplete> on wlan0" - its also weird as it is connected via ethernet cable...

Comment: To find the MAC address, type the command `ifconfig` in terminal.

Comment: I`m not that noob :) If you dont have access to that machine you cannot run ifconfig to find out its mac address...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when u have this error :

```
ssh: connect to host port 22: No route to host
```

you can't reboot it without beeing physically there.

That's why my ubuntu servers are always Virtual Machines, so i can reboot them if something happens. Of course if my server crashes i can't do much, but calling my wife to reboot it :)

Comment: you are welcome. if it was helpful, you can mark or upvote the answer.