# Schedule boot on old hardware

Tags: boot, server, schedule

I've turned an old desktop in a home server. I would like to be able to boot and shutdown on schedule. Shutdown is easy with a cronjob. The boot part is tricky. 
This is an old Pentium 4. There is no wake on alarm option in de BIOS.
I'm almost afraid that what I want is not possible with my old hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the Wake-on-lan feature. This is a fairly simple feature that has been around for years. 
There is a good how-to in here: http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Set_up_Wake-on-LAN_for_Ubuntu

Long story short:

1. Enable wake-on-lan in your old Pentium 4 (in the BIOS).
2. You turn it on on-demand by typing a command (or running a script) from a different computer (or phone/tablet/etc).

You can look at this in more detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47918/how-can-i-enable-wake-on-lan-permanently) and [here](http://lukasz-lademann.blogspot.mx/2013/01/how-set-up-wol-wake-on-lan-on-thin.html)

I did this around 2010 and back then I recall there was another option (and command) where you typed the command and the arguments included the MAC address, making this OS independent.I didn't look for this but if the previous suggestions don't work out for you you may want to search for this as well.

Comment: In this setting I don't have another wired device to send the magic package. I've tried with an old android device but I'm having trouble with sending (or receiving) the package over wireless.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have now is using a raspberry pie to send a WoL package to the server on a scheduled time.

Comment: Please explain in the answer how you set it up, Ethernet or WiFi, static or dynamic IP etc.