# How to automatically enable Wake-on-LAN for a network interface on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, 20.04, wakeonlan, systemd-networkd

Ubuntu's networking stack is constantly evolving and most previous information on enabling Wake-on-LAN for an interface is outdated (like the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan)).

Now that Ubuntu uses Netplan instead of `/etc/network/interfaces`, how do I enable Wake-on-LAN automatically whenever a particular interface comes up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wiki tells us we need to run `ethtool -s <interface> wol g` when the interface comes up.

Although Ubuntu 20.04 has `ifupdown` scripts under `/etc/network/if-up.d`, Netplan provides different guidance on [how to run post-up hook scripts](https://netplan.io/faq/#use-pre-up%2C-post-up%2C-etc.-hook-scripts) that suggests using `networkd-dispatcher`.

The manual page for `networkd-dispatcher` does not explain how to detect *which* interface is going down but [the source code](https://gitlab.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher/-/blob/master/networkd-dispatcher#L370) shows several environment variables that get set including `IFACE`.

So we can create `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/50-wake-on-lan` (and `chmod +x` it) with a script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -eu

case "$IFACE" in
    enp60s0)
        ethtool -s <interface> wol g
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by adding a file to /etc/netplan, named /etc/netplan/50-wol.yaml

the contents of the file are: (fill in your own mac-address).

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      match:
        macaddress: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
      wakeonlan: true
      dhcp4: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

For me really helped this post:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/troubles-with-setting-up-wol/24815/3

TLDR:
execute `sudo systemctl disable tlp`

> TLP is for power management on laptops etc.
> It is unlikely that you will need TLP on a system that you want to be able to remotely start a machine.

After execution of the command above WoL became persistent and you don't need to apply netplan after every reboot.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1292191)